# Web.config rewrite rule http to https and angular route combination

Tags: angular, iis

I have the following rewrite rules at IIS for an angular application:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When someone browses http://www.example.com, its being redirected to https://www.example.com, but when I use a route that setup the website, for example:

http://www.example.com/layout/dark it is not redirecting to https://www.example.com/layout/dark

I am wondering if Im making a mistake when adding two rules, and it should be all added into one rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the http to https rule first and try again. If it still does not work, you can use failed request tracking to view detailed error reasons.

[Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).